# Error in solve.default(A, B, fractions = TRUE) : 'a' (3 x 2) must be square

Tags: r, linear-algebra

I am currently learning the basics in matrices and vectors. And I am having this problem with this code :

```
 A <- matrix(c(1, -1, 2, 2, 3, 1),
            nrow = 3,
            ncol = 2,
            byrow = T)
B <- c(2, 1, 3)

solve(A, B, fractions = TRUE)
```

> Error in solve.default(A, B, fractions = TRUE) : 'a' (3 x 2) must be square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling around, it looks like you're trying to do something using the `matlib` package. You need to install the package if you haven't already, and use `Solve()` instead of `solve()` (R is case-sensitive):

```
library(matlib)
Solve(A,B, fractions=TRUE)
```

Comment: Oh! thanks so much I didn't notice my s was not capitalized much respect to you I hope you live long and prosper!